# Is it really a comcoin?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, base-conversion

### Very interesting background

Comcoins are a currency like any other. The residents of Multibaseania (an economically robust system of city-states with very few residents in a galaxy far, far away) use Comcoins to conduct transactions between themselves. Comcoins are represented by unique codes on special not-paper slips, and when you pay you give the vendor your slip.

However, just like any currency, there are those villainous types that try to take advantage of the system and inflate the currency because they are bored.

To combat this unquestionably illegal behavior, the Multibaseanian governments came together and devised a way to prove that the money is legitimate. The top idea from the think tank was: whenever a Comcoin is given to a vendor, the vendor runs a program that checks if it is legitimate. How does one know if a Comcoin is legitimate?

> **A legitimate Comcoin is one where:**
>
> When the Comcoin's unique code is converted into the bases 2-10, inclusive, that number is composite (i.e. not prime). Also, all of the unique code's digits in base 10 are either 1 or 0, and its length in base 10 is between 1 and 5 inclusive.

**Very important example:** in base 5, 111 is 421. Even though 111 is not prime, 421 is, so the Comcoin is invalid.

### The challenge

Write a function or program that takes a Comcoin's code (a number), which is in base 10 and is an integer. Then, print or return a truthy or falsy value depending on whether that Comcoin is legitimate (criteria above), respectively.

### I/O examples

```
Input     Output

101         False // because it is prime in base 2
1010        True
10101       True
1010111     False // because it is longer than 5 digits
123         False // because it does not contain *only* 0's and 1's
10111       False // because it is prime in base 6
```

This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Edit

A Comcoin is not a number that is not prime, but is a number that is composite.

[Inspiration from qualification round of Google CodeJam 2016.](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p2)

Comment: [Related...](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p2)

Comment: [Also related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/primes-in-different-bases)

Comment: What's with all the primality testing and base conversion? I know this was inspired by a Google code jam question, but I feel like these topics have been way overdone on PPCG. And my [comments from here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/primes-in-different-bases#comment189244_77541) also apply.

Comment: What about an input of `1`? It's not composite in any base, nor is it prime. Is it a legitimate Comcoin?

Comment: "*When the Comcoin's unique code is converted into the bases 2-10, inclusive, that number is composite*" makes no sense. The divisibility properties of a number are independent of the way the number is represented.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, not really. I *think* that what is going on is that the base-*b* representation of the number is interpreted *as though* it were in base 10, which is a two-step process, so the wording needs to show the two steps.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, I just noticed. I assumed this was the same as the GCJ challenge, but you're right it seems to be the other way round. So convert to base n and then reinterpret as base 10.

Comment: "To minimize the risk of SpaceWikiLeaks finding out about this whole manoeuvre, the code needs to be as short as possible"

Comment: I keep reading this as "Is this a comicon"

Comment: Well you definitely solved the inflation problem if you can only ever mint 18 comcoins...

Comment: Having to explicitly check for invalid input is annoying and in some submissions ends up being longer than the actual core of the problem.

Comment: @Mego all the challenge is about distinction between valid input and invalid input

Comment: Still no answer about input 1 ...

Comment: @edc65 The meat of the challenge is "determine if a number is composite in all bases 2-10". Having to also handle invalid input (too long or too short and not all digits are 0 or 1) unnecessarily complicates the challenge. Handling invalid input was not a part of the original Google Code Jam challenge, and I'm not sure why the author felt the need to tack that on when they copied the challenge and posted it here.

Comment: @Mego you mean this other challenge http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/primes-in-different-bases#comment189244_77541. Here many answers including mine have no composite/primality check at all

Comment: @edc65 No I mean the Google Code Jam challenge linked on the first comment

Comment: If you're going to argue over 1, what about 0? I'd really like it to be invalid, as that will cut my answer by about 40%.

Comment: @KevinLau - as just 1 is not composite (even though it is not prime), it is not a Comcoin

Comment: @Neil , see edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 20 bytes

```
n6<G50<9:Q"G@ZAZp~vA
```

Input is a string.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bjY8RzUwPDk6USJHQFpBWnB-dkE&input=JzEwMTAxJw)

#### Explanation

```
n6<    % take input implicitly. Is length less than 6?
G50<   % push input again. Array that contains true for digits less than 2
9:Q    % push array of bases: [2,3,...,10]
"      % for each
  G    %   push input again
  @    %   push current base
  ZA   %   interpret input as if it were in that base, and convert to decimal
  Zp~  %   true for composite numbers
  v    %   concatenate vertically all results up to now
  A    %   true if all results were
       % end for each implicitly
       % display implicitly
```

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <strike>62</strike> <strike>56</strike> 49 bytes

```
lambda n:max(`n`)<"2"and 0x5d75d750>>int(`n`,2)&1
```

Credit to @Sp3000 for the `max` trick to ensure binary digits.

Comment: A black magic hardcode of all relevant primes? Nice, how does it work?

Comment: @KevinLau It's function should be apparent once you realize how many 5-digit binary numbers there are :)

Comment: You left out 1111.

Comment: @xsot Fixed, had a little bug in my generation script.

Comment: wow... that's clever.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>38</s> 27 bytes

```
n=>2641714512>>'0b'+n&n<1e5
```

Port of @orlp's Python answer, except that JavaScript's precedence and weak typing allows me to shift the integer even if it's not valid in base 2, and then bitwise and it with the boolean. Returns 0 or 1 as appropriate. Note that I'm not using @orlp's constant any more, instead I'm assuming the following list of comcoins is valid:

> 100
>  110
>  1000
>  1010
>  1011
>  1100
>  1110
>  10000
>  10010
>  10100
>  10101
>  10110
>  11000
>  11010
>  11011
>  11100
>  11111

Edit: Fixed to check the length of the comcoin, since JavaScript's shift operator works modulo 32.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```
f(x,s="$x")=endof(s)<6&&all(c->c∈"01",s)&&!any(b->isprime(parse(Int,s,b)),2:10)
```

This is a function that accepts an integer and returns a boolean. It's a straightforward check on the conditions of being a Comcoin:

- Length as a string between 1 and 5 inclusive: `endof(s)<6`
- All zeros and ones: `all(c->c∈"01",s)`
- No primes in any base from 2 to 10: `!any(b->isprime(parse(Int,s,b)),2:10)`

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37

<s>This should work better than the current ES6 answer</s> Now the other ES6 answer is clearly better

**Edit** 0 and 1 not valid, the magic number changes

```js
n=>180006585..toString(2)['0b'+n-4]|0
```

**Test** (see below to see how the magic number is built)

```js
F=n=>180006585..toString(2)['0b'+n-4]|0

console.log=(...x)=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

function test() {
  var x=+I.value
  console.log(x+' '+F(x))
}

test()

// How the mask is built

isPrime=x=>{
  if(x<=2)return x==2
  if(x%2==0)return false
  var i,q=Math.sqrt(x)
  for(i=3;i<=q;i+=2)
    if(x%i==0)return false
  return true;
}

buildMask=_=>{
  var n,m,i,p,mask=''
  for(i=1;i<32;i++)
  { 
    n=+i.toString(2)
    for(p=0,b=10;b>1;--b)
    {
      m=+n.toString(b)
      p=m<2 || isPrime(m)
      if(p)
      {
        console.log('N',i,n,m,b)
        break;
      }
    }  
    mask+=p?0:1
    if(!p) console.log('Y',i,n)
  }    
  console.log(mask, parseInt(mask,2))
  // result
  // 0001010101110101010111010111001,180006585}
}
```

```html
<input value='11111' type='number' id=I oninput='test()'><pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 74 bytes

Anonymous function, takes input as a string and returns `true` or a falsy value (`false` if it fails a prime check, `nil` if it contains characters that aren't `0` or `1`)

Uses some regex magic suggested by @QPaysTaxes, which thankfully works (within reasonable time) because of the promise that the coin signature has max 5 characters. Also, I forgot to actually check for the length, so only 1 byte was saved overall.

Since `0` and `1` aren't composite numbers in any base, I could save more bytes by modifying my regex.

```
->n{n=~/^[01]{2,5}$/&&(2..10).map{|b|?1*n.to_i(b)=~/^(..+?)\1+$/}&[p]==[]}
```

Old version using Ruby's built-in prime checker. **85 bytes** after properly checking for length.

```
->n{require'prime';n=~/^[01]{1,5}$/&&(2..10).map{|b|Prime.prime? n.to_i(b)}&[!p]==[]}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can check primality in fewer bytes with this dark magic: `'1'*n.to_i(b) !~/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/`. Or at least I think you can. To be honest, I have no idea how that works, so it might not.

Comment: Oh! A regex pattern for composite numbers, and a check to make sure it doesn't match. Yeah, that'll work. (The black magic works by turning the number into a string of 1s and uses regex groups to find a pair of numbers that will multiply and fit the pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 97 bytes

```
#<1*^5&&Tr@DigitCount[#][[2;;-2]]<1&&FromDigits@IntegerDigits[#,a+1]~Table~{a,9}~NoneTrue~PrimeQ&
```

Hey, at least I tried...

```
#<1*^5&&Tr@DigitCount[#][[2;;-2]]<1&&FromDigits@IntegerDigits[#,a+1]~Table~{a,9}~NoneTrue~PrimeQ&
#<1*^5&&                                                                                          less than 100000?
        Tr@DigitCount[#][[2;;-2]]<1&&                                                             no digits 2-9?
                                     FromDigits@IntegerDigits[#,a+1]~Table~{a,9}~NoneTrue~PrimeQ& composite in all bases?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΘIg5›ITLBpàI1K`O_
```

-1 byte and bug-fix thanks to *@Grimmy*.

Outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3AzPdNNHDbs8Q3ycCg4v8DT0TvCP///f0MDAAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/czMq000fNeyqDPFxKji8oNLQO8E//r/O/2hDQ0MdQwMwNgATECZY2MhYB8qKBQA) or [verify the first 40 binary numbers and 100 regular numbers](https://tio.run/##ATUAyv9vc2FiaWX/NDBMYtGCTMKrdnlEPyIg4oaSICI//86YeWc14oC6eVRMQnDDoHkxS2BPX/8s/w).

**(Now longer) 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative:**

```
46bICèIт@Ig6‹PITм+
```

Outputs `1` for truthy and a non-1 integer for falsey (note: only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, so [this is allowed according to the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210)).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxCzJ0/nwCs@LTQ6e6WaPGnYGeIZc2KP9/7@hgYEBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/X8Ts6RK58MrKi82OVSmmz1q2BlQGXJhj/Z/nf/RhoaGOoYGYGwAJiBMsLCRsQ6UFQsA) or [verify the first 40 binary numbers and 100 regular numbers](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX/NDBMYtGCTMKrdnk/IiDihpIgIj//NDZieUPDqHnRgkB5ZzbigLlQeVTQvCv/LP8).

Both programs also works for edge-case `1`, unlike some other answers.

**Explanation:**

```python
Θ       # Check if the (implicit) input is exactly 1 (1 if 1; 0 otherwise)
Ig      # Push the input again, and pop and push its length
  5›    # Check if this length is larger than 5 (1 if length>5; 0 if length<=5)
I       # Push the input again
 TL     # Push a list in the range [1,10]
   B    # Convert the input to each of those bases
    p   # Check for each whether it is a prime (1 if prime; 0 if not)
     à  # Pop and push the maximum to check if any are a prime
I       # Push the input yet again
 1K     # Remove all 1s
   `    # And push all remaining digits separated to the stack
O       # Sum all values on the stack
 _      # And check whether it is exactly 0 (1/truthy if 0; 0/falsey if >0)
        # (after which this result is output implicitly)

46b     # Push 46 as binary: 101110
   IC   # Push the input, and convert it from binary to an integer
        # (NOTE: unfortunately also works for non-binary inputs, so we'll fix those later)
     è  # Use that to index into the 101110 (0-based and with wraparound)
Iт@     # Push the input again, and check that it's >= 10
Ig6‹    # Push the input again, and check that its length is < 6
P       # Take the product of all values on the stack
 I      # Push the input again
  Tм    # Remove all 1s and 0s
    +   # And add any remaining digits to the product
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 128 bytes

```
[ dup [| a | 2 10 [a,b] [ a swap base> prime? not ] all? ] swap [ [ [ 49 = ] [ 48 = ] bi or ] all? ] [ length 6 < ] bi and and ]
```

I'll try to golf this more in a sec.

Well, here's the *less* golfed version I thought might be shorter, but it's 133 bytes...

```
[ [ [let :> a 2 10 [a,b] [ a swap base> prime? not ] all? ] ] [ [ [ [ 49 = ] [ 48 = ] bi or ] all? ] [ length 6 < ] bi ] bi and and ]
```

Actually ungolfed:

```
: comcoin? ( a -- t/f ) 
  [
    [let :> a
      2 10 [a,b] [ a swap base> prime? not ] all? 
    ]
  ] [ 
    [ [ [ 49 = ] [ 48 = ] bi or ] all? ] 
    [ length 6 < ] bi 
  ] bi 
  and and ;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>161</s> 152 bytes

*Sigh*. Assign the lambda to use it.

```
def p(n):
 i=a=n
 while i>2:i-=1;a*=n%i
 return a>1
lambda s:all([all(map(lambda i:not p(int(s,i)),range(2,11))),filter(lambda i:i in"01",s)),len(s)<6])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 222 bytes

I wanted to try to do the naive method purely functionally, without looping. Here it is.

```
(lambda A:all([F(A)for F in[lambda r:all(map(lambda s:not(lambda i,b:lambda n:list(filter(lambda i:not n%i,range(2,n)))(int(i,b))(r,s),range(2,11))),lambda r:0!= len(filter(lambda d:d not in"01",r)),lambda r:0<len(r)<6]]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(lambda A:
    all(
        [F(A) for F in [
            lambda r: all(
                map(
                    lambda s:
                        not(
                            lambda i, b:
                                lambda n:
                                    list(filter(
                                        lambda i: not n % i, range(2, n)))
                            )(int(i, b))(r, s),
                            range(2, 11))),
            lambda r: 0 != len(filter(lambda d: d not in "01", r)),
            lambda r: 0 < len(r) < 6
            ]
        ]
    )
)
```